# ANDROID. Using a Customized Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter. Retrieving Images From Web

Tags: android, bitmap, android-arrayadapter

Hi I am using a customized android listview with custom arrayadapter from a tutorial on this website for my application.

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

In the MainActivity.java they have:

```
Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[]
    {
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_showers, "Showers"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_snow, "Snow"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_storm, "Storm"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_sunny, "Sunny")
    };
```

What I want to do is retrieve images from the web such as http://spe.atdmt.com/ds/NMMRTSMGUWDS/121114_reddit/Win8_wiki_728x90_v2.jpg

and use it instead of R.drawable.*

I have tried converting a URL link to a Bitmap image then changing a couple lines of code in

Weather.java:

```
from public int icon; to public Bitmap icon;
```

and

```
from public Weather(int icon, String title) to public Weather(Bitmap icon, String title)
```

WeatherAdapter.java:

```
from holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon); to holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(weather.icon);
```

I must not totally understand the code. I hope someone can help me out here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll have to start by actually downloading the images (using [this implementation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html), for example). Once you asynchronously download the images to some temporary directory, you can use [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to open those files and get the `Bitmap` objects that you need.

You should also look into [lazy loading the images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) into your `ListView`.